# Auto increment a variable in session

Tags: php

How do I auto increment a value inside a session which will be used multiple times in a certain page.

Comment: `$_SESSION['value']++`? Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_SESSION['value']++` will do the trick, then output your variable on the page

`<?php echo $_SESSION['value']; ?>`

Something to consider is that $_SESSION['value'] should be set first, perhaps at the top of your page. You can add this if you wish to check:

`<?php echo isset($_SESSION['value'])?$_SESSION['value']:''; ?>`